# How do I create a custom report type with Campaign and Person Account

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, campaign, campaign-member

**Background**

I have these objects:

1. `Person Account`
2. `Appointment`
3. `Invoice`
4. `Invoice Line`

Which have these relationships:

1. `Appointment` has a lookup to `Person Account`
2. `Invoice Line` has a **master-detail** lookup to `Invoice`
3. `Invoice Line` has a lookup to `Appointment`

The `Person Account` object has a roll-up called `Total Revenue`

I can add a `Person Account` as a `Campaign Member` of a `Campaign`

But I cannot create a Custom Report Type which allows me to `SUM` the `Total Revenue` for all `Campaign Members`

Because the custom report builder will only let me make `Campaign` relate to `Contact` or `Lead` and not `Person Account`.

**Question**

1. How can I create a `Campaign` based report that reports on `Person Account` fields?

Comment: I think you can create report type where `Campaign` relates to `Contact`. You will get `Person Account` fields there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a report type where `Contact` should be a primary object. When you click `Add fields related via lookup` this will let you select the PA fields.

Comment: @Rob, does above solution resolved your problem?